# Dual monitor DVI & VGA

Tags: graphics-card, vga, dvi

I have two monitors - one connected by DVI and the other connected by VGA; they are connected to the motherboard's integrated graphics. I would like to extend my screen. My motherboard has one DVI and one VGA port located on the backside of my tower.

Am I able to use screen extend if I have an integrated graphics card? My CPU is currently the graphics card for my PC.

PC specs:

- Processor: AMD Quad Core A6-3600 Accelerated
- RAM: 8GB DDR3
- Motherboard: [MSI A55M-P33 FM1 AMD A55](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813130641&nm_mc=TEMC-RMA-Approvel&cm_mmc=TEMC-RMA-Approvel-_-Content-_-text-_-) - Micro ATX
- OS: Windows 7 Home Premium

My motherboard is capable of using any AMD Radeon HD 6000 series graphics cards.

Comment: Then how are these monitors even connected?

Comment: I'm with @JourneymanGeek If there is no video card, and there is no integrated video on the motherboard, what exactly are these two monitors connected to?  You do specifically state that they *are* connected.

Comment: In which case you either have a IGP in your chipset or processor. There is in fact a graphics adaptor of some flavour installed. You may also want to state your OS, come to think of it

Comment: If you don't have a physically separate card, then you probably do have "integrated" graphics from your motherboard which are also known as "on-board" graphics. Without non-integrated and integrated graphics, you can't have any screen at all; which was what your question suggested before the edit...

Answer (score 0):

This is a very unclear question.

Are you saying that you want to use the extended screen feature of Windows with a monitor attached to each of the two video outputs?

If that is the question and as the motherboard quoted does NOT have integrated graphics, the answer should be **YES**. Because it is likely that you are using an add-in PCI graphics card and if it has two output connectors, it will almost certainly support output on both together.

However, you may need to install the appropriate video drivers from the graphics card vendor.